# vectorization : too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

```
a=b=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
i=np.arange(3)
mask=a<i[:,None,None]+3
```

and

```
b[np.where(mask[0])]
>>>array([0, 1, 2])

b[np.where(mask[1])]
>>>array([0, 1, 2, 3])

b[np.where(mask[2])]
>>>array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Now I wanna vectorize it and print them all together, and I try

`b[np.where(mask[i])]` and `b[np.where(mask[i[:,None,None]])]`

Both of them show `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you want at all. In particular, `np.where(mask[0])[0]` is all `True`s because the truth value of arrays is taken (and is `True` if at least one element is true), and also you are using both return values from `np.where()`, which I don't think is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [165]: a
Out[165]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [166]: mask
Out[166]: 
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

So `a` (and `b`) is (3,3), while `mask` is (3,3,3).

A boolean mask, applied to an array produces a 1d (same when applied via `where`):

```
In [170]: a[mask[1,:,:]]
Out[170]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

The `where` on the 2d mask produces a 2 element tuple, which can index the 2d array:

```
In [173]: np.where(mask[1,:,:])
Out[173]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32))
```

`where` on the 3d mask is a 3 element tuple - hence the `too many indices` error:

```
In [174]: np.where(mask)
Out[174]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

Let's try expanding `a` to 3d and apply the mask

```
In [176]: np.tile(a[None,:],(3,1,1)).shape
Out[176]: (3, 3, 3)
In [177]: np.tile(a[None,:],(3,1,1))[mask]
Out[177]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The values are there, but they are joined.

We can count the number of `True` in each plane of `mask`, and use that to `split` the masked tile:

```
In [185]: mask.sum(axis=(1,2))
Out[185]: array([3, 4, 5])
In [186]: cnt=np.cumsum(mask.sum(axis=(1,2)))
In [187]: cnt
Out[187]: array([ 3,  7, 12], dtype=int32)

In [189]: np.split(np.tile(a[None,:],(3,1,1))[mask], cnt[:-1])
Out[189]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

Internally `np.split` uses a Python level iteration.  So iteration on the `mask` planes might be just as good (6x faster on this small example).

```
In [190]: [a[m] for m in mask]
Out[190]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

---

That points to a fundamental problem with the desired 'vectorization', the individual arrays are (3,), (4,) and (5,) shape.  Differing size arrays is a strong indicator that true 'vectorization' is difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to print a vector it can only exist in the x, y and z dimensions. You have 4.

Comment: Have you never seen a vector with more than 3 dimensions?